# Grails 3 and MySql with utf8mb4 encoding

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

Having read an article [How to support full Unicode in MySQL databases](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4), I've realized that it would make sense to switch MySql encoding completly to utf8mb4. However, it brings the problem with index keys as they shouldn't be longer than 191 characters (255 in utf8mb3). By default, Grails String is mapped by gorm to VARCHAR(255) which is fine for utf8mb3. But how would I change this to VARCHAR(191) for utf8mb4.

The only solution I found was to set global default constraint which force all Strings to be mapped to VARCHAR(191). The problem is that it influence obviously the constraint for all String which is not desired in my case.

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    // set maxSize to 191 as we use MySql utf8mb4 whhich limits columns to 191 when used as indexes
    '*'(maxSize: 191)
}
```

Is there any way how to influence VARCHAR length. Maybe using something like user-type?

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    'user-type'(type: my.custom.ZoneIdUserType, class: ZoneId)
}
```

Or is there any better way how to deal with complete UTF-8 encoding for MySql anf Grails?

Answer (score 0):

The 191 was a temporary problem.  ("Temporary" in that it was created in 5.5 days, then finally fixed by default in 5.7.)

191 = 767/3

Meanwhile, here are 5 workarounds:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes